# Summations - Closed Form - Where to Start

Tags: algorithm, math, sum, series, recurrence

I am struggling to understand basics as it related to forming a closed form expression from a summation. I understand the goal at hand, but do not understand the process for which to follow in order to accomplish the goal.

> Find a closed form for the sum k+2k+3k+...+K^2. Prove your claim

My first approach was to turn it into a recurrence relation, which did not work cleanly. After that I would attempt to turn from a recurrence relation into a closed form, but I am unsuccessful in getting there.

Does anyone know of a strong approach for solving such problems? Or any simplistic tutorials that can be provided? The material I find online does not help, and causes further confusion.

Thanks

Comment: Factor out the `k`, now you have k times a finite arithmetic series from 1 to k. The sum of a finite arithmetic series is given by n*(a_1+a_n)*d, where a_1 is the first term, a_n is the last term, n is the number of terms, and d is the constant difference between adjacent terms. So your final sum is k(k*(1+k)*1)=k^2(1+k)=k^2+k^3.

Comment: @Asad This was helpful. Thank you. Is this a general approach for ALL summations or just ones that happen to contain a finite arithmetic series (do all summations have such a series?)

If you would like to repost as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @Busturdust Different types of sequences have different closed form expressions for their partial and infinite sums, and most sequences don't have any closed form expression for their sum. This seems like something you need to consult your discrete math textbook on; doesn't seem to have much to do with programming.

Comment: @asad artihmetic series is actually (n*(a_1 + a_n)*d)/2 actually right? does this mean the above is incorrect... the answer I got is K((K+K^2)/2)

Comment: @Busturdust Yes that's right, sorry. It's supposed to be /2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one gave the mathematical approach, so I am adding the mathematical approach to this AP problem.

Given series is 1k + 2k + 3k + .... + k.k(OR k^2)

Therefore, it means that there are altogether k terms together in the given series.

Next, as here all the consecutive terms are greater than the previous term by a constant common difference,i.e., **`k`**.

So, this is an Arithmetic Progression.

Now, to calculate the general summation, the formula is given by :-

```
S(n) = n/2{a(1)+a(n)}
```

> where,S(n) is the summation of series upto n terms
>
> n is the number of terms in the series,
>   a(1) is the first term of the series, and
>   a(n) is the last(n <sup>th</sup>) term of the series.

Here,fitting the terms of the given series into the summation formula, we get :-

S(n) = k/2{1k + k.k} = (k/2)*{k+k^2) =* `[(k^2)/2 + (k^3)/2]`*.

Comment: Hi Shekhar, if possible, could you please provide how to prove this claim mathematically? Is english based understanding good enough to prove this?

Comment: No, you have to think mathematically! So, the best resource for this to learn would be `"First to start with Arithmetic Progression"`. It'll help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a general algorithm to compute sums like these (and more complicated ones) I can't recommend the book A=B enough.

The authors have been so kind to make the pdf freely available:

http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Asad has explained a mathematical approach in the comments to solving this.

If you are interested in a programming approach that works for more complicated expressions, then you can use Sympy in Python.

For example:

```
import sympy
x,k = sympy.symbols('x k')
print sympy.sum(x*k,(x,1,k))
```

prints:

```
k*(k/2 + k**2/2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am looking for the mathematical approach as it will be a written test, but this seems to be a greaty way for checking answers for myself.